# Convert Javascript Image Rotator to play a Youtube video

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, youtube

I am hoping someone might have some suggestions on how to make a javascript image rotator play a youtube video as well...  Meaning instead of a static picture - have a video play and then go to the next photo.  I did not create the code of this rotator and think I understand how it works - just can't wrap my head around to make it play a video(if it is even possible).  The person who created the site appears to have gotten the code from Dynamic Drive. Here is the code:

```
var variableslide=new Array()
//variableslide[x]=["path to image", "OPTIONAL link for image", "OPTIONAL text description (supports HTML tags)"]


//configure the below 3 variables to set the dimension/background color of the slideshow

var slidewidth='546px' //set to width of LARGEST image in your slideshow
var slideheight='400px' //set to height of LARGEST iamge in your slideshow, plus any text description
var slidebgcolor='#000060'

//configure the below variable to determine the delay between image rotations (in miliseconds)
var slidedelay=6000

////Do not edit pass this line////////////////

var ie=document.all
var dom=document.getElementById

for (i=0;i<variableslide.length;i++){
var cacheimage=new Image()
cacheimage.src=variableslide[i][0]
}

var currentslide=0

function rotateimages(){
contentcontainer='<center>'
if (variableslide[currentslide][1]!="")
contentcontainer+='<a href="'+variableslide[currentslide][1]+'">'
contentcontainer+='<img src="'+variableslide[currentslide][0]+'" border="0" vspace="3">'
if (variableslide[currentslide][1]!="")
contentcontainer+='</a>'
contentcontainer+='</center>'
if (variableslide[currentslide][2]!="")
contentcontainer+=variableslide[currentslide][2]

if (document.layers){
crossrotateobj.document.write(contentcontainer)
crossrotateobj.document.close()
}
else if (ie||dom)
crossrotateobj.innerHTML=contentcontainer
if (currentslide==variableslide.length-1) currentslide=0
else currentslide++
setTimeout("rotateimages()",slidedelay)
}

if (ie||dom)
document.write('<div id="slidedom" style="width:'+slidewidth+';height:'+slideheight+'; background-color:'+slidebgcolor+'"></div>')

function start_slider(){
crossrotateobj=dom? document.getElementById("slidedom") : ie? document.all.slidedom : document.slidensmain.document.slidenssub
if (document.layers)
document.slidensmain.visibility="show"
rotateimages()
}

if (ie||dom)
start_slider()
else if (document.layers)
window.onload=start_slider

</script>

<b>
<ilayer id="slidensmain" width=&{slidewidth}; height=&{slideheight}; bgColor=&{slidebgcolor}; visibility=hide><layer id="slidenssub" width=&{slidewidth}; left=0 top=0></layer></ilayer>
```

So basically you add the images to the array variableslide[].  What I was hoping for is a way to add a youtube video you that array or by some other method... I am sure there is a way it can be done - but I unfortunately can't seem to google the correct thing to make this happen.  Any suggestions???

Comment: That code seems to be from the last century... (`<ilayer>` etc.)

Comment: Yeah - I think you are right. I guess I am going to look into another solution.

Answer (score 1):

This is just my opinion, but the code you posted in your question seems suspect at best. I'd recommend trying out something else entirely.

I know the prettyphoto jQuery plugin does what you're looking to do. I'm using it on a site right now for a gallery that has both photos and video. http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyphoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/